# Not getting enough attention on other SE sites

Tags: discussion, bounties

I have a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927027/to-have-php-5-3-2-openssl-1-0-1-ubuntu-16-04) related to PHP and Ubuntu OS. Mostly related to Ubuntu. So I asked that question in Ask Ubuntu. But the question is not getting enough attention. Only 5 views after posting it for a long time, an hour.

Even to mark as bounty I have to wait 2 more days. I neither have the reputation nor the time.

Suppose if I had asked in Stack Overflow I may have got more attention and response for that question.

But, posting the same question on two different SE sites is not recommended. So what would be the correct next step now? Delete the question from Ask Ubuntu and post it on Stack Overflow with [php] tag as it is related to PHP too?

Comment: I would not consider 1 hour as a long time. I think that is the problem you are encountering. Instead look at 3 or 4 days as being a long time, and just be patient.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Not an exact dupe, I think, but only a partial dupe. This question focuses more on "Getting Attention", though.

Comment: @RoryAlsop a long time varies. If I am trying to get out of a fire, or if I have two minutes to fix some code before losing a business contract an hour is a very, very long time. If I have complete a dissertation it's not very long at all. I think what siddiq was trying to tell you is that from siddiq's perspective this is a long time to wait.

Comment: @iBug: I picked the dupe target that focused more on attention, not enough answers, and the like. There may be a better one but I didn't find it.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter: Unfortunately, Stack Exchange can't be relied on to fix code in two minutes. "A long time" should primarily be considered not from the *asker's* perspective, but from the *Stack Exchange* perspective. And an hour isn't that long on any site.

Comment: What Nathan said - if you are in an emergency situation, do not expect SE to give you your solution. That is not what it is for.

Comment: But as I mentioned, suppose if I had asked in "StackOverflow" I may have got more attention and response for that question.

Comment: And you might have not. There is no guarantee. Ask a question on the site whose scope it fits most. And be patient.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Stack Exchange is supposed to be here to serve the public. When that ceases to happen, given its power over massive sections of internet geography, directly and indirectly, that starts to be a problem.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter: As always, projects are defined by what they say "no" to. SE very deliberately and carefully does *not* claim to be the be-all, end-all of Internet help. SE can help in many areas, but refuses to guarantee (or even attempt) full coverage of all topics or all needs. And "I need an answer to a new question within minutes" isn't serving "the public", but *the asker*. That's of decidedly secondary importance.

Answer (score 9):

No, it is not generally acceptable to post-delete-and-repost a question on another site simply because it did not get an *immediate* answer. Folks may already be working on your post, so it is not fair to them to ask for help and then remove it shortly thereafter.

**First I would improve your title** and state the problem you're actually having. At a glance I have no idea what you are asking — the title lists a bunch of technologies (+ versions) expecting the users to dig further into the post just to see what its about (i.e. "Can I possibly answer this?"). You miss a lot of traffic if you raise the bar to include only folks motivated enough to dig that far into the post.

Before you start looking to add bounties or to re-post your question on another site, there's enough **due diligence here to improve, clarify, and document your continued efforts first.**

Answer (score 2):

You said that you posted it on ask ubuntu because it is mostly related to Ubuntu. But you also mentioned Php. So, the choices are Stack Overflow and Ask Ubuntu and you choose ask Ubuntu.

Stack Overflow is a site for professional programmers and enthusiasts. So you could have asked it in SO if you sure that it will be on topic in SO.

Since you asked it in Ask Ubuntu, you don't have to do anything other than wait for 2 days and place a bounty.

Deleting it from there and ask on SO is not a good choice. That will work only if the post is off topic in SO.

In such case, if the question is completely off topic there and is on topic in SO, then mod's may migrate it. Or you can ask it if the post is closed saying off topic.

At present, all you have to do is go to **Ask Ubuntu chat rooms** and ask for help. But please don't spam there.

**you can also share the link to that post in PHP chat rooms in SO and ask for help**

#### In future

If you have a question that may fit in 2 sites, then read the help of both sites and choose the most fit one. Just for getting more attention, if you posted it in a site in which the post is partially on topic, you may get more attention but you may not get a perfect solution.